# How do logging frameworks like Log4j guarantee log statement ordering?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, circular-buffer

This question has been bugging me for a while, how do popular logging frameworks like Log4j which allow concurrent, async logging order guarantee of log order *without performance bottlenecks*, i.e if log statement `L1` was invoked before log statement `L2`, `L1` is guaranteed to be in the log file before `L2`.

I know Log4j2 uses a ring buffer and sequence numbers, but it still isn't intuitive how this solves the problem.

Could anyone give an intuitive explanation or point me to a resource doing the same?

Comment: Not entirely sure what is actually used in the implementation, but I would use a FIFO-Queue, and a single worker which works that queue

Comment: But even then given that you would be concurrently adding to the queue, how would you ensure that two events would be added in order of generation to the FIFO queue.

Comment: The log4j2 [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html) states: "_Asynchronous Loggers internally use the [Disruptor](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#UnderTheHood), a lock-free inter-thread communication library, instead of queues, resulting in higher throughput and lower latency_". You might be able to look into that to see an implementation.

Comment: I looked at it, Disruptor is basically a ring-buffer which I mentioned in my question. However AFAIK, disruptor is basically a replacement for queue, but the problem is if you have concurrent submissions to a queue, how do you guarantee submission of one that was created before would be submitted before too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This all depends on what you mean by "logging order". When talking about a single thread the logging order is preserved because each logging call results in a write.

When logging asynchronously each log event is added to a queue in the order it was received and is processed in First-in/First-out order, regardless of how it got there. This isn't really very challenging because the writer is single-threaded.

However, if you are talking about logging order across threads, that is never guaranteed - even when logging synchronously - because it can't be. Thread 1 could start to log before Thread 2 but thread 2 could get to the synchronization point in the write ahead of thread 1.  Likewise, the same could occur when adding events to the queue. Locking the logging call in the logging method would preserve order, but for little to no benefit and with disastrous performance consequences.

In a multi-threaded environment it is entirely possible that you might see logging events where the timestamp is out of order because Thread 1 resolved the timestamp, was interrupted by thread 2 which then resolved the timestamp and logged the event. However, if you write your logs to something like ElasticSearch you would never notice since it orders them by timestmap.